# CSS Section Background Button Section Question

Tags: html, css, border

I have attached an image, and I am wondering how to accomplish this with CSS. I will show what I have and what I would like to accomplish. If you are able to provide a solution, thank you so much in advance! (This is specifically relating to the little box and border around the buttons :))

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYFu1.png)

[What I would like to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Bgb.png)

Comment: Please provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you've tried and a more specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have buttons like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Add to Wishlist</button>
  <button class="btn">Add to Shopping Cart</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.buttons-wrapper .btn{
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Change values according to your liking !

Answer (score 0):

I would use an HTML table: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

You can create 2 columns and style the content in each cell accordingly.